# How to center the contents inside of a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the contents of a  tag. This is the div that I am trying to center:

```
<div class="Paging" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="PageOfPage" style="display:inline-table;padding: 10px;">

        Page<label id="CurrentPage">1</label> From @Model.CountPage
    </div>
    <div class="RecordsOfRecord" style="display:inline-table;padding: 10px;">
        Record
        <label id="FromRecord">
            @{
                 int i1 = (Model.CurrentPage-1)*Model.CountRecordInPage;
                 if (i1 == 0)
                 {
                     i1 = 1;
                 }

                 string recordFrom = i1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
             }@recordFrom
        </label>
        To
        <label id="ToRecord">@Model.CountRecordInPage</label>
        From @Model.AllRecord
    </div>
</div>
```

There must be something that I am missing, but I am out of ideas.

Comment: can you also post your css styles? or maybe create a simple jsfiddle with the problem ?

Comment: I do not use css file.

Comment: Inline CSS is a nightmare to maintain.  You should seriously consider using an external style sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use

```
<div class="Paging" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;">
```

[`Live Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/9pTH3/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a width of your div if you want to use margin: auto

```
.Paging {
width :70%;
margin : auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a width to the div!! 
or if you want the text to be centered add
text-align:center;